# Finding out whether checkboxes are checked or not

Tags: jquery, forms, input, radio-button

I want to validate the radio buttons in a form with jQuery, but it doesn't work. Even if I check a radio button the code below (variable "checked") returns false.

What am I doing wrong?

```
        $('.radio').each(function(){
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if($(this).is(':checked') === false){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Comment: ummm... why do you have 3 equal signs in $(this).is(':checked') === false)? should they be 2 equal signs like $(this).is(':checked') == false)?

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code here. As per your code it suggest each radio button having a class called radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  $('.radio').each(function(){
            var checked = $(this).attr("checked") == "checked";
            if(checked){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $('.radio').click(function(){               
                if($(this).is(':checked') == false){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
    });
```

use `$(this).is(:checked)`  or `$(this).attr('checked')` to get the status of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('.radio').each(function(e){
            var checked = this.checked;  // using this.checked is better
            if(!checked){  // not checked
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

or if you want to `:is(':checked')` then

```
        $('.radio').each(function(e){
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if(!checked){  // not checked
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! However, something is wrong here as it seems. Even if I check all of the radio buttons "checked" is set to false. :/

Comment: @holyredbeard do you pass `e` arguments to `.each()` callback